# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Migration keyword not supported userid

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I try to do a migration, I get this error. I am using SQL Server Express.

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'userid'.    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Dictionary`2 synonyms)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.RelationalLoggerExtensions.MigrateUsingConnection(IDiagnosticsLogger`1
>   diagnostics, IMigrator migrator, IRelationalConnection connection)
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) Keyword not supported: 'userid'.

This is my connection string that is located in my `appsettings.json` file:

```
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBNAMEONE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;UserId=USERNAMEONE;Password=PASSWORDONE
```

I have tried removing the `UserId` completely from the string but I still get this error. I am unsure of how to continue as on another application, this connection string works properly.

Comment: You should use `User Id` instead of `UserId`: `Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBNAMEONE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=USERNAMEONE;Password=PASSWORDONE`.

Comment: I tried User Id as well. Is this userid being set somewhere else?

Comment: Thats strange. It suddenly worked once I restarted my Visual Studio.